# Do the Sages tell us why Ezekiel's wife died?

Tags: commentaries, agada-stories-legends, ezekiel--the-book

> Also the word of the Lord came to me, saying, Son of man, behold, I am
> about to take away from thee the delight of thy eyes at a stroke: yet
> thou shalt neither mourn nor weep, nor shall thy tears run down. Sigh
> in silence; make no mourning for the dead, bind on thy turban, and put
> on thy shoes upon thy feet, and cover not thy lips, nor eat the bread
> of men. So I spoke to the people in the morning: and at evening my
> wife died; and I did in the morning as I was commanded.
> [Ezekiel 24-15-18](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.24.15-18?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Is there anything in rabbinic literature that tells us why Ezekiel's wife died?

Answer (score 5):

The ArtScroll version of Yechezkel cites different mefarshim that explain why the wife of Yechezkel died.

The [Radak](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.24.16?lang=bi&p2=Radak_on_Ezekiel.24.16.1-4&lang2=bi) explains that she was not sick, but died without warning in the plague that befell the city of its sins.

The [Abarbanel](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.24.15?lang=bi&with=Abarbanel&lang2=en) writes along the lines that when a whole city is sinful, even the righteous persons among them are punished.

The [Malbim](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.24.16?lang=bi&with=Malbim&lang2=en), in his commentary to Yechezkel 24:16 explains that she died because of the plague:

> הנני לקח הודיעו שאשתו תמות במגפה, וצוהו שלא יספד, ואף לא יבכה, ואף שלא יבואו דמעותיו כלל:

The [Metzudos Dovid](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.24.16?lang=bi&p2=Metzudat_David_on_Ezekiel.24.16.1-4&lang2=bi) explains that it was a sudden dead during the plague.

See the [Chomat Anakh](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.24.16?lang=bi&with=Chomat%20Anakh&lang2=en) for a bonus on the relationship between the wife of Yechezkel and Kain and Hevel.

In Tractate Derech Eretz Zuta 9:18, it [says](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.24.16?lang=bi&with=Tractate%20Derekh%20Eretz%20Zuta&lang2=en):

> If you withheld yourself from performing a meritorious act and occupied yourself with a sinful act, your wife will ultimately die of a stroke, as it is stated, Son of man, behold, I take away from thee the desire of thine eyes with a stroke

[There](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/112374/jewish/The-Prophet-Ezekiel.htm) are also commentaries that explain the death of Yechezkels wife to symbolize the destruction of the Holy Temple.

Comment: Seems a little odd that Sefaria translates מגפה as "stroke".

Comment: I do not know why they translated מגפה as stroke. It needs to be plague or pandemic.